# HTML5 Canvas putImageData not functioning as expected

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am using html5 canvas for some image manipulation. I want to introduce functionality to change background color of the canvas. So I let the user pick a pixel from where to start changing the background color and provide me with a new color. I then iteratively move through the surrounding pixels to modify color. However it seems that context.putImageData is not changing the color. The code looks something like below:

```
//c represents the pixel where we want to start changing color
function Fill(c){
   var oldColor = context.getImageData(c.x1,c.y1,1,1);
   var NewColor = {};
   NewColor.red = 33;
   NewColor.green = 0;
   NewColor.blue = 0;
   bucketFill(c.x1,c.y1,oldColor.data,NewColor);
}

function getColor(x,y){
    var tempData = context.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
    var colorString = JSON.stringify(tempData.data);
    return colorString;
  }

  function setColor(x,y,NewColor){
    var tempData = context.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
    tempData.data[0] = NewColor.red;
    tempData.data[1] = NewColor.green;
    tempData.data[2] = NewColor.blue;
    context.putImageData(tempData,1,1);
  }

  function bucketFill(x,y,oldColor,NewColor){
    if( (x<0) || (x>canvas.width) || (y<0) || (y>canvas.height) ){
      return;
    }
    if(getColor(x,y) != JSON.stringify(oldColor)) {return;}

    setColor(x,y,NewColor);
    bucketFill(x-1,y-1,oldColor,NewColor);
    bucketFill(x-1,y,oldColor,NewColor);
    bucketFill(x-1,y+1,oldColor,NewColor);
    bucketFill(x,y-1,oldColor,NewColor);
    bucketFill(x,y+1,oldColor,NewColor);
    bucketFill(x+1,y-1,oldColor,NewColor);
    bucketFill(x+1,y,oldColor,NewColor);
    bucketFill(x+1,y+1,oldColor,NewColor);
  }
```

So the issue here is that SetColor function is not setting new color to the background

Answer (score 0):

You must putImageData back where you found it.

putImageData has these parameters (imageDataObject, x-coordinate, y-coordinate).

```
context.putImageData(tempData,x,y);   // not putImageData(tempData,1,1)
```

Just thoughts...

You're not setting the alpha component of the pixel (tempData.data[3]).  This means if the pixel was transparent (data[3]===0) then the replaced color will not show (it's also transparent).  I'm assuming that's what you desire, but I'll mention it anyway.

Also, since getImageData/putImageData are rather costly operations, it's more common to perform all pixel array modifications before doing putImageData.

- getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)  // get all the pixels
- modify all pixel data as desired  // change all pixels as desired
- putImageData(tempData,0,0);  // put all the modified pixels back on canvas in 1 push

JSON is a rather expensive way of comparing data.  You might use javascript objects instead.

Without enough coffee I'm not sure, but it looks like your hyper-recursive bucketFill might cause endless loops in some cases.  Here's a nice alternate example of floodfill by William Malone:  http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/

Comment: Thanks mark..  I did make these observations myself and modified the also.